# How do I find the error details using the match function on Lua?

Tags: lua, minecraft, computercraft

I'm just asking a question on finding error details from the error function.

Like I would like to find error details from `example.lua:50: "then" expected near "if"`.

Any ways on how to do that on Lua? I'm working on something for ComputerCraft on Lua. (Minecraft Java mod)

**EDIT:**

I'm trying make a function that returns the error parsed out. It's supposed to return 3 variables, var1: file name, var2: line number (if none it is specified nil), var3: error text.

Answer (score 1):

`example.lua` is the file where the error is. `50` is the line number. There is a syntax error, likely in the `if` condition. (I'm not familiar with ComputerCraft, so I don't know where that file might be.)

Comment: I'm at least looking at and figuring out to get details of the error using a function.